# Can I run multiple instances of SpiderOak?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, cloud-storage

I want to synch different folders that belong to different SpiderOak accounts. Can I run more than one instance of SpiderOak at the same time? Can I set them both up to start at startup?

(I need instructions for both an Ubuntu 11.10 machine and a Windows 7 machine. I'm guessing that on Windows I can just install it twice into different folders?)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install second application inside "virtual machine" and use it on both Windows and Ubuntu.